# 17.04 unable to add Facebook to online accounts

Tags: login, password, security, facebook

I am trying to add a number of accounts using the **Online Accounts** dialog in **System Settings**. I was able to add Google successfully but I am unable to add Facebook. The following steps show what happens in my case:

- Click **Add account** button in left-hand panel.
- A list of accounts including Facebook appears in the right-hand panel.
- Click on the Facebook icon.
- A Facebook login dialog appears.
- Enter email address and password.
- Select **Keep me logged into Ubuntu** check box.
- Click the **Log In** button.
- The password is rejected even though I successfully logged into Facebook from Firefox on the same machine immediately prior to starting this procedure using the same password. It is not a typing error as I get the same problem repeatedly using this dialog, yet I am always able to login with the same password to Facebook when using Firefox.

What do I need to do here?

Comment: Does your password contain any special characters or spaces... ie: not alphanumeric?

Comment: Yes it does and the password is accepted and used by Facebook in other environments. The problem seems to be restricted to the Online Accounts subsystem.

Comment: So try changing your Facebook password to just alphanumeric characters and then retry the Online Accounts. Report back.

Comment: This would do little expect show whether this dialog has a limitation. I am not prepared to dumb down my passwords to meet inadequate and obsolete password standards.

Comment: Note how my first comment was about special characters in your password. Why do you think I asked that? So why don't you try my suggestion to see if that's it. You can always change it again later, but it would tell us if there was a limitation in the software (on either end). Don't ask a question, ask for help, and then drop the hammer and say that **I just won't try that**. You probably won't get much help after that. Just sayin.